# Reinitialize Vue.js component after DOM changed after ajax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a PHP application with Vue.js advantage. The main vue obj looks as so:

```
window.vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Also there are some globally registered components.
There are already tabs that are linked through ajax (re-render DOM html). In one of them I want to add a Vue component

```
<widget-pro></widget-pro>
```

After loading I see registered component inside Vue instance, but it is not initializing. If I manually call new Vue() it will be initialized, but other components will be broken.

Comment: Vue can't know about DOM modifications you make outside of Vue; if possible make your ajax calls from within a Vue component, and use its data on the component scope to let Vue render the DOM instead of doing it manually.

Comment: Obviously, this is the better way. But main question is how to do it (initialize) manually.